# Range remains the same when repeatedly reading a filtered sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with several categories, and a worksheet with a pivot table.

I'm filtering by category, creating a new workbook, copying the pivot table worksheet and the filtered category to the new workbook. I repeat the process with every category.

My problem is the first category range is correct, but when I re-query the range for the other categories, the range remains the same.

```
For i = 1 To 10 '10 categories
    ...
    Set Data_sht = NewBook.Worksheets("Temp")
    Set Pivot_sht = NewBook.Worksheets("Category")
    PivotName = "PivotTable2"
    Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A1")
    Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
    Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache NewBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
    ....
Next i
```

The NewRange on the first pass (category) has 545 rows. I've verified this to be correct. The NewRange on the second pass (category) still contains 545 rows, even though it should be 260 rows.

Is there a way to force a re-read of the Data_sht (data sheet)?

Thanks.

Comment: *I'm filtering by category* - I don't see this anywhere in your code. However, if you really are using `AutoFilter` method on your range. Look into `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` I think this will help you get what you need.

Comment: What about? Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: SpecialCells(xlLastCell) is the last cell in the used range, not the last cell with value

Answer (score 0):

I found something strange, but it solved my problem.

```
NewRange = "Temp!A1:X" & LastRow(ActiveSheet)

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    'Excel doesn't seem to return the true count until the WS 
    'is queried a second time. Bug?

    For i = 0 To 2
        On Error Resume Next
        LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Function
```

Hope this helps someone.